# How to stop slide to go to next on slide.bs.carousel event, same like return false we use in forms to stop submit?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap carousel on my site and want to add some condition on slide.bs.carousel event so slide will stop to go on next slide, if any specific condition not met.

I'm using `.carousel('pause')` method to achieve this but its not working, below is the complete snippet of my code:

```
jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    alert("Please select one");
    jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('pause');
});
```

My carousel HTMl is:

```
  <div id="carousel-personal-loan" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row per-loan-gender">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row male_or_female">
                        <div class="quote-title">My gender</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <a href="#" class="selected_Quote_Item">
                                <img src="male" />
                                <span>Male</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="female.jpg" />
                                <span>Female</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <div class="row per-loan-sources">
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row sal_or_selfemp">
                        <div class="quote-title">Are You</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 male">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="sal.jpg" />
                                <span>Salaried</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 female">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="self-emp.jpg" />
                                <span>Self-employed</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-personal-loan" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

The thing is if user use his/her gender than he/she will go to next slide, otherwise will stay on that slide to force user to select his/her gender

Anyone there who know this event and method, please help

Comment: Post all of the code please

Comment: do you see the alert though?

Comment: Yes, I think I have find out solution myself, I have added carousel:pause in place of jQuery('#carousel-personal-loan').carousel('pause');

Comment: Really sorry, I think this is not the solution I have found, its actually error and carousel stop working. @techLove Yes alert showing

Comment: @ZimSystem I have added complete HTML as well, please check